# ReactJS - How could I wrap the cell text in MaterialTable when typing in data for a new row?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

**Question**: Is it possible to wrap text when typing in abnormally long names in MaterialTable?

An issue I'm having with the Material Table is when typing in a very long name, for example "LONG NAME LONG NAME LONG NAME LONG NAME" the line continues, and the previous words "disappear".

Is there a way to wrap the text so when I'm typing a really long name, the text field continually expands?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vnk66

The current issue:

[image: Current Issue]

What I want to try and do, where the text wraps inside the box.

[image: What I would like to do]

What I've tried to do was inline styles in the MaterialTable declaration, and then in the outer  element I have, but this doesn't work:

```
style = {{
    whiteSpace: "normal", 
    wordWrap: "break-word",
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize components in order to have them behave exactly as you want in editable material tables. For example, if you want to have a multiline `TextField` you can do:

```
columns: [
  {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    editComponent: ({ value, onChange }) => (   
      <TextField
        onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
        multiline
      />
    )
  },
  ...
]
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8ysj5